# What is wrong with my reasoning regarding tensor products?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra

$\def\Rbb{\mathbf{R}}$
Let $F$ be a subfield of the field $K$ and let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$. Then $K\otimes_FV\cong K^n$.

Considering the case when $F=K=\Rbb$ and $V=\Rbb^1$, I have
$$
\Rbb\otimes_\Rbb\Rbb^1=\Rbb^1(=\Rbb)\;.
$$

On the other hand, let $V$ and $W$ be two (finite-dimensional) vector spaces over the field $F$. Then
$$
V\otimes_F W\cong L(V,W;F)\;,
$$
where $L(V,W;F)$ denotes the set of all the bilinear maps from $V\times W$ to $F$.

If I let $V=W=\Rbb^1$, and $F=\Rbb$, then
$$
\Rbb^1\otimes_\Rbb\Rbb^1
\cong L(\Rbb^1,\Rbb^1;\Rbb)
\cong \Rbb^2
$$

But $\Rbb^1$ cannot be isomorphic to $\Rbb^2$. What is going wrong here?

I guess one cannot "identify" $\Rbb^1$ and $\Rbb$ when talking about tensor products since one is a "vector space" while the other is a "field".

Comment: Your $L(V,W;F)$ denotes the $F$-linear maps from $V$ to $W$?

Comment: OK -  Then your $L( {\mathbb R}^1 \times  {\mathbb R}^1 ;  {\mathbb R})$ doesn't "parse" - namely, your $V = {\mathbb R}^1 \times  {\mathbb R}^1 $, but what is $W$?

Comment: on the other hand, the $\mathbb R$-linear maps from ${\mathbb R}^1$ to itself is one-dimensional over the reals.

Comment: It should be $L(ℝ^1,ℝ^1 ; ℝ^1)$ instead of $L(ℝ^1 × ℝ^1 ; ℝ^1)$. And we rather have $(V ⊗_F W)^* ≅ L(V,W ; F)$. The isomorphism you wrote is valid only if $V$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional, and it's not canonical.

Comment: @Dabouliplop typo? you meant $V^*\otimes_F W \simeq L(V,W;F)$...

Comment: @peterag No no, I mean $(V ⊗_F W)^* = L(V ⊗_F W ; F) ≅ L(V,W;F)$. Maybe you're thinking about the fact that $V^* ⊗_F W$ is the space of linear maps $V→W$ with finite rank?

Comment: I see you edited your question by replacing $L(ℝ^1×ℝ^1 ; ℝ)$ by $L(ℝ,ℝ ; ℝ)$, but then why would you have $L(ℝ,ℝ ; ℝ) ≅ ℝ^2$?

Comment: @Dabouliplop: Thanks. So I believe the mistake is in $L(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R};\mathbf{R})\cong \mathbf{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, I think so. A bilinear map $ℝ × ℝ → ℝ$ is given by *one* number, not two. Any bilinear map $ℝ×ℝ→ℝ$ is of the form $(x,y) ↦ αxy$ for some parameter $α ∈ ℝ$.

Comment: @Dabouliplop I guess it's not clear what the OP wants the $L$ to denote - I was indeed thinking that it meant the space of linear maps $V$ to $W$ - see my (first) question/comment

Comment: @peterag Ah, ok. I think $L(A,B ; C)$ means the space of bilinear maps $A×B→C$. It's a notation I often saw.

Comment: @Dabouliplop: Thanks. So I believe the mistake is in $L(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R};\mathbf{R})\cong \mathbf{R}^2$. The set $L(\mathbf{R},\mathbf{R};\mathbf{R})$ is the *bi-linear* functional on $\mathbf{R}^2$ instead of *linear* functionals; the later is usually denoted as $L(\mathbf{R}^2;\mathbf{R})$ and is of dimension two.

Comment: @peterag: Sorry for the confusion. My previous comment is incorrect. The notation $L(V,W;F)$ should be interpreted as the bilinear maps from $V\times W$ to $F$. Ultimately, I believe this is also isomorphic to the set of $F$-linear maps from $V$ to $W$ (in the finite dimensional case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\def\Rb{\mathbf{R}}$
Thanks to the helpful comments from `Dabouliplop` and `peter a g`, I identify the mistake is in $L(\Rb^1,\Rb^1;\Rb)\cong \Rb^2$.

This is incorrect. The notation $L(\Rb^1,\Rb^1;\Rb)$ denotes the set of all the *bilinear* maps from $\Rb^1\times \Rb^1$ to $\Rb$. It is different from the space $L(\Rb^1\times\Rb^1,\Rb)$, which consists of all the *linear* maps on $\Rb^1\times\Rb^1$.

The dimension of $L(\Rb^1,\Rb^1;\Rb)$ is $1$, while the dimension of $L(\Rb^1\times\Rb^1,\Rb)$ is $2$.